# Displaying Google Chart with info from a Datasource

Tags: php, html, mysql, json, google-visualization

I'm currently trying to show a google chart that's populated with info I'm pulling from a data source. I have a connection to the data base established, I can query the data I want and store the results in a json object. What I'm having trouble with is displaying the chart. I'm close, but not there yet. Here is what I have  in my php code

```
`<?php


  $mysqli =mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'prueba');
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: ".mysqli_connect_error();
}

  $sql = mysqli_query($mysqli, 'SELECT * FROM pizza');

  if (!$sql) {
  die("Error running $sql: " . mysql_error());
  }

   $results = array(
       'cols' => array(
           array('label' => 'Topping', 'type' => 'varchar'),
           array('label' => 'cantidad', 'type' => 'number')
       ),
       'rows' => array()
   );

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
   $results = array(
      'Topping' => $row['Topping'],
      'cantidad' => $row['cantidad']
   );
   $results ['rows'][] = array('c' => array(
       array('v' => $row['Topping']),
       array('v' => $row['cantidad'])
   ));
}
$json = json_encode($results,  JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
echo $json;

?>`
```

Then, my html code for the chart:

```
     <head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
      google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

      // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
      // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
      // draws it.

      function drawChart() {

        // Create the data table.
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost/cakesetup/pizza',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (jsonData){
                var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

        // Set chart options
                var options = {'title':'Distribucion de pizzas',
                                'width':800,
                                'height':600};
                    }
        // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
            var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
        });
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
  </body>
</html>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I run the code what I get is this "{"Topping":"Peperonni","cantidad":6,"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"Peperonni"},{"v":6}]}]} "

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check your url

```
// Create the data table.
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/cakesetup/pizza', // i dont think a url localhost will work. try cakesetup or /pizza
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (jsonData){
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);

    // Set chart options
            var options = {'title':'Distribucion de pizzas',
                            'width':800,
                            'height':600};
                }
    // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
        var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    });
```